# Request Entity Too Large error on POST (PHP)

Tags: php, post, curl, http-post

I have a text box which has lots of data on it when I submit the form I get the error in the console

```
POST http://www.XXX.com/save.php 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
```

My PHP.INI file is below

```
allow_url_include = On 
post_max_size 100M
upload_max_filesize 100M
LimitRequestBody 1024000
```

Why do I get this error? How can I Fix it?
I am posting data of I think around 2-3 Mb. ( Its HTML of a webpage )

This is the webpage, this data should be sent to the php on SAVE button  http://caarve.com/highlight.php?page=en.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLydia_Zinovieva-Annibal

Comment: Check your error logs for memory allocation errors. Once found, bump up the size to accommodate. If you have to upload a 4 GB video or something, look into doing chunked requests.

Comment: don't forget Apache's `LimitRequestBody` which gets applied long before PHP ever enters into the mix.

Comment: see this SO question: [request-entity-too-large-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718571/request-entity-too-large-php)

Comment: @BartFriederichs It should be less then 3MB, Its basically a webpage.

Comment: @MarcB - I used this too , and updated the Php.ini ( Now it is as above )

Comment: @didierc - I Tried this too :(

Comment: @adi: that's an apache directive for httpd.conf, NOT a php.ini directive.

Comment: if these parameters don't have an impact on the error, would you be kind to show us the relevant bit of code dealing with this form?

Comment: @MarcB - Oh Ok , I Added it to .Htaccess but still nothing happened.

Comment: @didierc - This is the webpage, this data should be sent to the php on SAVE button  http://caarve.com/highlight.php?page=en.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLydia_Zinovieva-Annibal

Comment: I don't think that `allow_url_include` makes a difference.

Comment: @didierc - I added the link to the live site, Can you have a look ? For small pages it works fine.