# javascript php upload images request entity too large

Tags: php, image, upload

I have php javascript images upload problem. When I upload about 20kb, it is OK.
But when I upload over 500kb, it fails and displays the error shown below. My web site is hosted on godaddy. In my local development computer it works and runs smoothly. Do you have any ideas??

I have tried:

`ini_set('post_max_size',52428800);` // 50 MB

`ini_set('upload_max_filesize',52428800)` // 50 MB
But does not work.

//------ERROR on Web Pag----------

> Request Entity Too Large 
>    The requested resource /index.php/newPost/ does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

//------------My code----------------------//

```
function uploadImages($input, $file)
{

    if($input == null || $input == "")
    {
        return false;
    }
    $stringVal = $input; 
    $value  = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $stringVal);

    if ($this->check_base64_image($value) == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $actualFile  = base64_decode($value);
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($actualFile);
    $imgSize = getimagesize('data://application/octet-stream;base64,' . base64_encode($actualFile));


    if ($img == false) {
        return false;
    }else
    {

        /*** maximum filesize allowed in bytes ***/
        $max_file_length  = 100000;

        log_message('debug', 'PRE UPLOADING!!!!!!!!');

        if (isset($img)){

            log_message('debug', 'UPLOADING!!!!!!!!');

            // check the file is less than the maximum file size
            if($imgSize['0'] > $max_file_length || $imgSize['1'] > $max_file_length)
            {
                log_message('debug', 'size!!!!!!!!'.print_r($imgSize));
                $messages = "File size exceeds $max_file_size limit";
                return false;
            }else if (file_exists($file)) {
                return false;
            }else
            {
                file_put_contents($file, $actualFile);
                return true;
            }
        }       
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718571/request-entity-too-large-php

Comment: And both `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` can __not__ be set via `ini_set`, as the PHP manual clearly states.