# Send large Json data to php via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I need to post large amount of json data to php file via ajax, but its is showing me 413 entity too large error.
I have tried using data type as json but it still shows the same error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    data: "ajax=true&action=manageSavedLayouts&a=" + result + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(productdb),
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        //  alert(result);
    }
});
```

This is the code i am using to make the ajax call and the variable which is causing problem is productdb.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Post method in ajax 
e.g
type: "POST"

Comment: no. it didn;t worked with type:POST

Comment: [413 - Request Entity Too Large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718571/request-entity-too-large-php/3719358#3719358)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        ajax: true,
        action: "manageSavedLayouts",
        a: result,
        b: productdb
    }
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: i have specified type as post datatype as json and passing the content as json also but it doesn't work it still gives entity too large error..any idea why??

Comment: "413 (Request Entity Too Large)" This is the error i get in console

Comment: @ShivikaSharma : What is your web-server ?

Comment: its apache, i have increased the post_max_size also but the issue is still there

Comment: type? shouldn't that be "method"? Please refer to jQuery documentation. You are having this error because there is a limit to the url size if I recall it right. And you still had the error when using "type": "post" as "type" serves to define the type of data expected from the response following the call. Using method should allow you to post the JSON.

Comment: **type** (default: 'GET')

An alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use type POST, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: "ajax=true&action=manageSavedLayouts&a=" + result + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(productdb),
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    //  alert(result);
    }
});
```