# Request Entity Too Large error on chunked plupload with plupload-handler-php example

Tags: php, file-upload, plupload

I'm pulling my hair out. Using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) with chunking on a php backend. Chunked (or non chunked for that matter) goes fine until I use files > 100mb.

I'd like to be able to use files until 1Gb. Keep getting the error, and then the retries kick in and percentage is at 0% again and restarting.
There is also no preflight OPTION request. I even made a quick NodeJS backend by using [node-pluploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pluploader), that handles chunks, but same problem and errors there (although that did send preflight OPTION).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Additional Apache directives

```
LimitRequestBody 0
```

PHP settings

```
file_uploads          On
max_file_uploads          20
max_execution_time          3600
memory_limit          640M
post_max_size          600M
upload_max_filesize          500M
```

js

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    url : '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>admin?sub=upload',
    silverlight_xap_url : '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>lib/Moxie.xap',
    multi_selection : false,
    max_retries: 10,

    filters : {
        max_file_size : '1024mb',
        chunk_size: '10mb',
    },

    init: {

        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                $('#document-file').html(file.name);
            });
        },

        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            $('#spinner-progress').html( " " + file.percent + "%" );
        },

        Error: function(up, err) {
            console.warn("Error #" + err.code + ": " + err.message);
        },

        UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
            console.log(files[0]);
        }
    }
});

uploader.init();
```

uploader backend

```
<?php
require_once(LIB.SLASH."PluploadHandler.php");

PluploadHandler::no_cache_headers();
PluploadHandler::cors_headers();

if (!PluploadHandler::handle(array(
    'tmp_dir' => UPL_TMP_PATH,
    'target_dir' => UPL_TMP_PATH
))) {
    die(json_encode(array(
        'OK' => 0,
        'error' => array(
            'code' => PluploadHandler::get_error_code(),
            'message' => PluploadHandler::get_error_message()
        )
    )));
} else {
    die(json_encode(array('OK' => 1)));
}
```

I'm using an unchanged [plupload-handler-php example](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload-handler-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request Entity Too Large PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718571/request-entity-too-large-php)

Comment: The answers in that topic did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a forced setting in ngnix config. The client_max_body_size was forced to 128m by a Plesk default template (default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php). On overruling this setting Plesk returned a "duplicate" error which eventually turned me to [this answer](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/client_max_body_size-duplicate-problem-still-exists.334148/#post-796028). Make a custom template, update vhosts. Problem solved!