# Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html2canvas

I'm getting the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413
> (Request Entity Too Large)

```
function pageSS() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://myweb/upload_ss.php',
                data: img,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `413 Request Entity Too Large` error occurs when a request made from a client is too large to be processed by the webserver. If your web server is setting a particular HTTP request size limit, clients may come across a `413 Request Entity Too Large` response. An example request, that may cause this error would be if a client was trying to upload a large file to the server (e.g. a large media file).

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489351/413-request-entity-too-large-error-during-file-upload-php) and configure your webserver to change the allowed upload limit.