# Request Entity Too Large apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

I have 8000 checkboxes in a form being submitted. No comments on how bad that is please.

My **.htaccess**

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 10000
```

I am getting the `Request Entity Too Large` error when I submit the form.

When I had 3000 checkboxes it was working fine. Am I missing some more settings or do I need restart a service other than apache?

**Aside:**
I checked my post size using

```
 postsize = $("form").not("[type='file']").serialize().length;
```

The result is `postsize == 165655`

Comment: Have you tried increasing the input variables size to something like 20000? Maybe the 10000 limit is being surpassed by your 8000 checkboxes and some other form elements.

Comment: just gave it a go and still same error. But also having too many checkboxes didn't give me that error when I had to increase max_inputs the first time...it just truncated the checkboxes with no error.

Comment: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#limitrequestbody

Comment: @hjpotter92 I put `LimitRequestBody 0` in my `.htaccess` but it didn't do anything to solve the problem

Comment: @Phil Can you check the Apache server logs? If so, please paste the relevant line here.

Comment: @hjpotter92 doesn't seem to have a relevant error in `var/log/apache2/error.log` The last entry is from a couple of hours ago (restart) even though I hit the error page a lot very recently.

Comment: @hjpotter92   http://tny.im/51F

Comment: It might be because of `RequestReadTimeout` directive also. Though, the docs say that it'd lead to an error code 408 and not 413.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I discovered my logs were configured per site to go to a different file. Looks like ModSecurity data length needs to be raised.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3718571/1741542

Comment: @hjpotter92  fixed it with `<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 5242880
</IfModule>` I credit you for getting me to look in the logs. please post answer for me to accept.

Comment: You should answer the question yourself. You can cite these comments for reference, but it was you who dug through the actual issue, and not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in the right log files see comments in OP, I discovered modsecurity was denying the post request and googling helped me find this solution.

Increase the size allowance by adding the following to the site configuration i.e. `etc/apache2/sites-available/[your_site.conf]`

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 5242880
</IfModule>
```

I used an arbitrary large number but you can use whatever number you feel comfortable with...you increase exposure/severity of DOS attacks along with the size.