# POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit

Tags: php, excel, .htaccess, php-ini

I'm facing this issue on 000webhost when I'm trying to upload excel file into database.

here is link of my test site [Test site for Excel Sheets](https://pakdeveloper.000webhostapp.com/)

There is a file with name of `largedata.xlsx` I'm trying to upload this file. [Here](https://pakdeveloper.000webhostapp.com/excelImport/excel_test.php)

It take some time but after this it show error message `POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.`

I searched about this and already update the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in `.htaccess` file you can check `info.php` for this detail. But still I'm facing this issue.

**.htaccess**

```
php_value post_max_size xxM
php_value upload_max_filesize xxM
```

Replace **xx** with your value.

Comment: So what do you want us to do? If the data exceeds the limit the process is killed for security reasons.

Comment: About that dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file)... Are you certain it is considered at all? You need to enable its interpretation first in your host configuration. Take a look at the `AllowOverride` directive for that in the documentation.

Comment: I want to ask is there any problem with my code or it is from hosting provider ???

Comment: We cannot say anything about your post obviously, since we do not know it. But I would not consider this a real problem at all, to me this looks like that system works as intended.

Comment: Are you using PHP-FPM?

Comment: @apokryfos yes I think you can check `phpinfo` here https://pakdeveloper.000webhostapp.com/info.php

Comment: @arkascha actually I need to insert records into database from excel sheet, this one is a large sheet 16MB how can I do that if post max size increase ?

Comment: You are not using PHP-FPM which means the `.htaccess` rules should work as long as you put them in an .htaccess which is the one being used by your page.

Answer (score 0):

413 errors occur when the request body is larger than the server is configured to allow. Here’s how you can fix it, depending on your web server:

```
Apache: Set the LimitRequestBody directive in either your httpd.conf file or a local .htaccess file. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719358/1688568)

Nginx: Set the client_max_body_size directive in nginx.conf (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/)

IIS: Set the uploadreadaheadsize config setting (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx)
```