# godday upload base64 image with backpack laravel ,Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, laravel-5, upload

I have a problem on Godday shared host I'm trying to upload an image base64
because i want to crop it  with Laravel Packpack, the image size is 4MG I update the php settings as the following

[screen shot for PHP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4hAt.png)

but i face this problem

[screen shot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POIed.png)

I cant change the apache settings or turn off mode security

Comment: Your code works with a smaller image?

Comment: How do you upload it?

Comment: yes the code working with small image and locally and I can upload any  file with 10MG size but when i try to upload image with base64 it's not working

Comment: Add this `LimitRequestBody` in a `.htaccess` file and see if it works. The documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719358/678611 But I will use POST method instead of GET if I was you.

Comment: i already set  LimitRequestBody in htacess file but it's not working

Comment: We need to see the code that do the request and send the image in base64 format

Comment: you can find the code from this link
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/fields/base64_image.blade.php