# Request Entity Too Large Laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cpanel

I'm having this issue, some times doesn't appear but other yes, I'm using a GoDaddy Hosting and I change the values in the CPanel on the PHP Selector

[PHP Selector prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbbo0.png)

But this doesn't fix anything. I'm using Laravel 8 as my Backend API, I was looking for an answer but I didn't find it, all what I found was about nginx and wordpress.

I'm sending some files like 1 pdf and 2 images which I compress to reduce the size. those images I send it as base 64 I'm using Angulas 11 as front

hope someone can help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request Entity Too Large PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718571/request-entity-too-large-php)

Comment: I did it, I set a image showing the values of memory_limit, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize, and that dosn't fix the problem

Comment: Let me rephrase ! Are you using docker ? I have no idea about GoDaddy and if you are using GoDaddy without a terminal, you have to change that 100% now, because how do you run migrations ? Commands ? you need to switch your server. What's the size of the files you are trying to get ? Do you have to "restart" GoDaddy instance maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to change your file uploading limit from cpanel. Then it will not show the err message.